# Why is the Jest mock instance empty when mocking a Node.js module?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm having some problems with mocking, I've mocked a node module by adding a **mocks**/ssh2-sftp-client.ts file:

```
const mockSsh2SftpClient = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    connect: async () => {},
    end: async () => {},
    on: () => {}
  }
})

export default mockSsh2SftpClient
```

This works, kinda. My tests run correctly using this mock, but in the tests SftpClient.mock.instances[0] is an empty mockConstructor {} object instead of this mock (ie. SftpClient.mock.instances[0].end is undefined). What am I doing wrong?
for reference, my testing code looks like this:

```
import { ConnectConfig } from 'ssh2'
import SftpClient from 'ssh2-sftp-client'
import { withSftp } from '../sftp'

// Type assertion to make TypeScript happy.
const MockSftpClient = SftpClient as jest.Mock<SftpClient>

describe(withSftp, () => {
  const mockConnectionConfig: ConnectConfig = {}

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Clear all instances and calls to constructor and all methods:
    MockSftpClient.mockClear()
  })

  it('should call the callback after successfully connecting', async () => {
    const mockCallback = jest.fn()

    // Instantiates SftpClient and calls connect, then the callback, then end.
    await withSftp(mockConnectionConfig, mockCallback)

    const mockInstance = MockSftpClient.mock.instances

    expect(mockCallback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(MockSftpClient.mock.instances[0].end).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

The last fails because MockSftpClient.mock.instances[0].end is undefined, where it should be a function.

Answer (score 7):

The mock constructor provided by `Jest` [only records `this` as the instance](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/ccea646e76efd73654468ac32b3cb3a88778f7f4/packages/jest-mock/src/index.ts#L538) so if your mock constructor returns a different object then that object won't be recorded in the `instances` array.

To get the behavior you are wanting just mock with a standard function and use `this`:

__mocks__/ssh2-sftp-client.ts

```
const mockSsh2SftpClient = jest.fn(function() {
  this.connect = jest.fn();
  this.end = jest.fn();
  this.on = jest.fn();
});

export default mockSsh2SftpClient
```

Comment: BIG EMPHASIS for whoever was here hours pulling the little hair that remains: is fundamental to export the mock `export default <your-mock>` as otherwise, the mocked object will be empty...