# Mocking classes imported from node_modules

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, bullmq

I am having a hard time using mocks for BullMQ in NodeJS with Typescript. I follow the [instructions](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks), the very related [example](https://www.dragonflydb.io/faq/testing-bullmq-jobs-with-jest-in-nodejs) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402005/jest-mock-how-to-mock-es6-class-default-import-using-factory-parameter).

The test case focuses on the initial setup that instantiates 3 Queues, adds a job in each of them and starts the corresponding workers. Note that the source code instantiates a Queue with: `import {Queue} from 'bullmq';` and `const newQueue = new Queue(...)`. Then job is added with `newQueue.add(...)`.

**Problem:** I cannot use a reusable mock object that can be defined in `__mocks__` directory ([Manual mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#manual-mock) in the documentation).
I use:

```
const mockAdd = jest.fn(() => console.log('test'));

const mockQueue = jest.fn(function () {
  return {
    add: mockAdd,
  };
});

const mockBullmq = jest.fn(function () {
  return {
    Queue: mockQueue,
  };
});

export { mockAdd, mockQueue, mockBullmq as default};
```

The result is `TypeError: bullmq_1.Queue is not a constructor`.

Because I use typescript ("target": "ES2020") with named import I also followed the advice in the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402005/jest-mock-how-to-mock-es6-class-default-import-using-factory-parameter) with no luck. The used code follows:

```
const mockAdd = jest.fn(() => console.log('test'));

const mockQueue = jest.fn(function () {
  return {
    add: mockAdd,
  };
});

const mockBullmq = jest.mock('./bullmq', function () {
  return {
    Queue: mockQueue,
  };
});

export { mockAdd, mockQueue, mockBullmq as default};
```

The test case is the following:

```
import queue from '@worker/queue';
import { Queue, Worker, add } from '@mocks/bullmq';

describe('Test queue setup:', () => {
  it('should connect to queues', async () => {
    await queue.setup();
    expect(Queue).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
    expect(Queue.mock.instances).toHaveLength(3);
    expect(add).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
    expect(Queue.mock.instances[0].add).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(Worker).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
  });
});
```

Comment: Your question needs a bit more focus on what you are asking. But a few pointers about using the `__mocks__`. First, these mocks are not automatically used unless you set `automock` to `true`, or you explicitly mock them by calling `jest.mock('moduleName')` or similar at the top of the test file. Second, the `__mocks__` example you show, all your exports are `mockXXX` but the naming should match the actual exports from the original module. This is a tricky subject to grasp so just keep trying.

Comment: @Nickofthyme, thank you very much. Renaming of exports helped. I will rephrase my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you kinda had the right idea from my comment but not exactly. Honestly, you really need to read through the [mocks docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks) and see how they say to do it because there are so many nuances based on each use case.

The general idea for mocking `node_modules` is that any matching module inside of `__mocks__/` is **automatically** used to mock the module in **all** tests regardless of whether [`automock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#automock-boolean) is `true` or whether you explicitly call `jest.mock('my-module')` or not. See docs [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) for more details.

So taking a look at your case I am going to simplify things a bit because you didn't provide the `setup` logic, but I'm confident you can apply this to your exact case. But imagine I have this `setup.ts` file I want to test below...

```
// src/setup.ts

import { Queue } from 'bullmq';

export function setup() {
    const queue1 = new Queue('default1');
    queue1.add('name1', {})
    const queue2 = new Queue('default2');
    queue2.add('name2', {})
    const queue3 = new Queue('default3');
    queue3.add('name3', {})
}
```

Then the tests I would then write as such...

```
// src/setup.test.ts

import { Queue } from 'bullmq';
import { setup } from './setup';

import { mocks } from '../__mocks__/bullmq';

// jest.mock('bullmq'); // not needed

describe('Test queue setup:', () => {
    it('should connect to queues', async () => {
        setup();
        expect(Queue).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
        expect((Queue as unknown as jest.Mock).mock.instances).toHaveLength(3);
        expect(mocks.add).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
    });
});
```

There are a few key things to note here. The first is how I import the `bullmq` mocks. Even though I am importing from `bullmq` as I normally would, this is actually importing the module from `__mocks__/bullmq` if it exists, I'll get to this file later. But you don't import directly from `__mocks__/` jest rewires this import under the hood. This applies to any `import` of this module in both tests and `src/` files!

The next thing is why am I importing `mocks` from `../__mocks__/bullmq`? I'll explain this more later but this is essentially a way to import other things that are not exports of the actual `bullmq` module.

Next is the `jest.mock('bullmq')` line, as I mentioned in the beginning this is not needed for mocking `node_modules`, see [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules).

Next is the `(Queue as unknown as jest.Mock)` type gymnastics, this is a way to coerce the default import type to be of the type `Mock`. The issue is that by importing the module directly from the `bullmq` the original types are used not the mocked types. But since we know there is a mock we must override this type as the underlying javascript object is in fact a mock, it just doesn't know it. There may be a better way to handle this but this is the quick and easy way.

Finally I removed the line you had as...

```
expect(Queue.mock.instances[0].add).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

In order to access the instance methods you must build the mock differently by applying the methods to the `this` context, see the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56400704/why-is-the-jest-mock-instance-empty-when-mocking-a-node-js-module) for more.

So now for the `__mocks__` file. Here the file name must match the module name, I think you could also do `__mocks__/bullmq/index.ts` if you'd like to organize your mock better.

```
// __mocks__/bullmq.ts
const add = jest.fn();

export const Queue = jest.fn(function() {
    console.log('mock Queue called')

    // This is done in order to access `mockFn.mock.instances`
    this.add = add;
    this.obliterate = jest.fn();
    this.getRepeatableJobs = jest.fn(() => []);
});

export const mocks = {
    add
};
```

Notice the `add` method is shared across all instances that are created using the `Queue` mock. Then I just add all these erroneous exports under `mocks` export. If I want to access the `add` method from inside a test file, I can import it using `import { mocks } from '../__mocks__/bullmq'` and using it from `mocks.add`, see how I did this in `setup.test.ts`. If you were to import `add` from `bullmq` you would get a type error as the original types don't have this export.

Back to the line about `expect(Queue.mock.instances[0].add).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`, I removed this as this would produce the same mock instance as the `mocks.add` for all instances of `Queue`. So maybe you can tweak this to assert what you wanted but it doesn't make sense as it was.

A helpful tip is adding `console.log` in your mocks to debug and ensure that they are actually being called.

I created a demo replit [here](https://replit.com/@npartri/jest-example#src/setup.test.ts). You can open the shell tab on the right and run `npm run test` to see the tests pass. The output is shown as...

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your time. I managed to get it working with your hints. I really appreciate the effort you put into this. Surely I have to study the jest documentation at its full extend.

Comment: However when I run it under github CI, the calls to the `add` Queue instances are not caught (`received 0` against `expected 3`).

Comment: Glad it helped you find the right solution. As far as the CI difference, nothing comes to mind how that could be different, it should run the same in both environments. It could be something with your dependencies if you are not locking your node modules. I would post a new question with as many details as you can about your environment.